# Objective C: How to get current UIFont from UIPickerView to calculate NSString length?

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, uifont, cgrect

For a modular `UIPickerView` within an `UIPopoverController` I need to calculate the maximum size (`CGRect`) of a `NSString`.

`UIPickerView` has one component. Values are single line strings.

To calculate the size, I need the current `UIFont` from the `UIPickerView`. The following  works for `UILabel`,

```
UIFont* fontFromUILabel = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:UILabel.font.pointSize];
```

but what's the equivalent for `UIPickerView`?

```
UIFont* fontFromUIPickerViewSelectedState = ????;

float maxWidth = 0.0f;
for(int i = 0; i < [MY_STRING_VALUES count]; i++){

    NSString* string = [MY_STRING_VALUES objectAtIndex:i];
    CGSize rect = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{
         NSFontAttributeName:fontFromUIPickerViewSelectedState }];

    if(rect.width > maxWidth){
        maxWidth = rect.width;
        NSLog(@"new MAX WIDTH: %f",maxWidth);
    }       
}
//...
//present UIPopoverViewController with calculated size
[_popOver setPopoverContentSize: CGSizeMake(maxWidth,200.0)];
[_popOver presentPopoverFromRect:[(UIButton*)sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:TRUE];
```

And yes, I could get the font from the xib, but this should be a modular solution which works every time!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [`viewForRow:forComponent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/viewForRow%3aforComponent%3a) to get one of the sub-controls to get its font.

Comment: sounds like a plan, but i cannot find any way to get the current `UIFont`? any suggestions?